Confusion about calculating Moment of Inertia of hollow sphere
A hollow sphere can be visualized as a stack of infinite rings varying in size,
While calculating the moment of inertia of a hollow sphere, why does the following logic falter?:
Assume compressing the hollow sphere from either side such that it results in 2 discs, Now why can't we simply state that moment of inertia of the hollow sphere = 2* (moment of inertia of the disc) because essentially we are finding the summation of the moment of inertia of infinite rings in either case.
The following pictures are sourced from : This video





It's hard to tell, but thinking somewhat geometrically, I expect that the result of projecting these rings down onto the x-y plane makes the density non-uniform in the disk, so that there is a larger density on the outside of the disk then on the inside. This would turn the 1/2 for a disk into a factor of 2/3 (which corresponds to the hollow sphere).

Consider to spell out acronyms.

You should have expected a factor of 4, not a factor of 2.
I'm going to take a shortcut and just use calculus.
Let us start by reviewing and deriving the areas of a disc and a sphere. The disc is easy, but a sphere will use some algebra. The integral getting the area of a disc is
$$A_d=\int\mathrm dS=\int_0^r2\pi R\,\mathrm dR=\pi r^2$$
whereas the integral getting the surface area of a sphere is $(z=+\sqrt{r^2-R^2})$
$$
\begin{align}
A_s=\int\mathrm dS&=\int_0^r2(2\pi)R\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\mathrm dz}{\mathrm dR}\right)^2}\mathrm dR\\
&=4\pi\int_0^r\frac{rR}{\sqrt{r^2-R^2}}\mathrm dR=4\pi r^2
\end  {align}
$$
where the 2 in front of $(2\pi)$ is due to upper and lower hemispheres.
We can now derive the MoI of both the disc and the sphere. For the disc, the density is $\rho_d=\frac m{\pi r^2}$ whereas for the sphere, the density is $\rho_s=\frac m{4\pi r^2}$
$$
\begin{align}
I_d&=\int R^2\,\mathrm dm=\int_0^rR^2\rho_d\,2\pi R\,\mathrm dR\\
&=2\pi\frac{r^4}4\left(\frac m{\pi r^2}\right)=\frac12mr^2\\
I_s&=\int R^2\,\mathrm dm=\int_0^rR^2\rho_s\,4\pi\frac{rR}{\sqrt{r^2-R^2}}\mathrm dR\\
&=4\pi\frac{2r^4}3\left(\frac m{4\pi r^2}\right)=\frac23mr^2
\end  {align}
$$

The idea is this: The video's derivation showed that one hemisphere's worth of area is transformed into two disc's worth, hence sphere's surface area = 4 disc's area. Note that the hemisphere, by conversion, first goes out, and then comes back in. This is "area preserving", but it is heavily redistributing the areal contributions. In the MoI computation, we insert the square of the radius, which will conflict with this redistribution, and that is why the video's argument will fail.
